# Flutter:- paint using Float32Int and drawRawPoints

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to paint using Float32Int and drawRawPoints but, it's showing that
bad state element.
I have created one list type of Float32Int and in Float32Int var, and then I am storing offset on by on in the list. in paint method using for loop, I am trying to paint. but it shwoing bad state of element in the console

```
library painter;

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' hide Image;
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class Painter extends StatefulWidget {
  final PainterController painterController;

  Painter(PainterController painterController)
      : this.painterController = painterController,
        super(key: new ValueKey<PainterController>(painterController));

  @override
  _PainterState createState() => new _PainterState();
}

class _PainterState extends State<Painter> {
  bool _finished;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _finished = false;
    widget.painterController._widgetFinish = _finish;
  }

  Size _finish() {
    setState(() {
      _finished = true;
    });
    return context.size;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child = new CustomPaint(
      willChange: true,
      painter: new _PainterPainter(widget.painterController._pathHistory,
          repaint: widget.painterController),
    );
    child = new ClipRect(child: child);
    if (!_finished) {
      child = new GestureDetector(
        child: child,
        onPanStart: _onPanStart,
        onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
        onPanEnd: _onPanEnd,
      );
    }
    return new Container(
      child: child,
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
    );
  }

  void _onPanStart(DragStartDetails start) {
    Offset pos = (context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox)
        .globalToLocal(start.globalPosition);
    widget.painterController._pathHistory.add(pos);
    widget.painterController._notifyListeners();
  }

  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails update) {
    Offset pos = (context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox)
        .globalToLocal(update.globalPosition);
    widget.painterController._pathHistory.updateCurrent(pos);
    widget.painterController._notifyListeners();
  }

  void _onPanEnd(DragEndDetails end) {
    widget.painterController._pathHistory.endCurrent();
    widget.painterController._notifyListeners();
  }
}

class _PainterPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final _PathHistory _path;

  _PainterPainter(this._path, {Listenable repaint}) : super(repaint: repaint);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    _path.draw(canvas, size);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_PainterPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class _PathHistory {
  List<MapEntry<Path, Paint>> _paths;
  Paint currentPaint;
  Paint _backgroundPaint;
  bool _inDrag;

  _PathHistory() {
    _paths = new List<MapEntry<Path, Paint>>();
    _inDrag = false;
    _backgroundPaint = new Paint();
  }

  void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
    _backgroundPaint.color = backgroundColor;
  }

  void undo() {
    if (!_inDrag) {
      _paths.removeLast();
    }
  }

  void clear() {
    if (!_inDrag) {
      _paths.clear();
    }
  }

  static List<Float32List> list = [];

  Float32List float32list;
  // Float32List floatPoints = Float32List.fromList(list);
  void add(Offset startPoint) {
    if (!_inDrag) {
      _inDrag = true;
      Path path = new Path();
      // path.moveTo(startPoint.dx, startPoint.dy);
      // _paths.add(new MapEntry<Path, Paint>(path, currentPaint));
      float32list.addAll([startPoint.dx, startPoint.dy]);
    }
  }

  void updateCurrent(Offset nextPoint) {
    if (_inDrag) {
      // path.lineTo(nextPoint.dx, nextPoint.dy);
      float32list.addAll([nextPoint.dx, nextPoint.dy]);
    }
  }

  void endCurrent() {
    _inDrag = false;
    list.add(float32list);
  }

  void draw(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    p.strokeWidth = 20.0;
    canvas.drawRect(
        new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height), _backgroundPaint);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list.isNotEmpty) canvas.drawRawPoints(PointMode.lines, list[i], p);
    }
  }
}

typedef PictureDetails PictureCallback();

class PictureDetails {
  final Picture picture;
  final int width;
  final int height;

  const PictureDetails(this.picture, this.width, this.height);

  Image toImage() {
    return picture.toImage(width, height);
  }

  Future<Uint8List> toPNG() async {
    return (await toImage().toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png))
        .buffer
        .asUint8List();
  }
}

class PainterController extends ChangeNotifier {
  Color _drawColor = new Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
  Color _backgroundColor = new Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

  double _thickness = 1.0;
  PictureDetails _cached;
  _PathHistory _pathHistory;
  ValueGetter<Size> _widgetFinish;

  PainterController() {
    _pathHistory = new _PathHistory();
  }

  Color get drawColor => _drawColor;
  set drawColor(Color color) {
    _drawColor = color;
    _updatePaint();
  }

  Color get backgroundColor => _backgroundColor;
  set backgroundColor(Color color) {
    _backgroundColor = color;
    _updatePaint();
  }

  double get thickness => _thickness;
  set thickness(double t) {
    _thickness = t;
    _updatePaint();
  }

  void _updatePaint() {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.color = drawColor;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = thickness;
    _pathHistory.currentPaint = paint;
    _pathHistory.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void undo() {
    if (!isFinished()) {
      _pathHistory.undo();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void _notifyListeners() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clear() {
    if (!isFinished()) {
      _pathHistory.clear();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  PictureDetails finish() {
    if (!isFinished()) {
      _cached = _render(_widgetFinish());
    }
    return _cached;
  }

  PictureDetails _render(Size size) {
    PictureRecorder recorder = new PictureRecorder();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(recorder);
    _pathHistory.draw(canvas, size);
    return new PictureDetails(
        recorder.endRecording(), size.width.floor(), size.height.floor());
  }

  bool isFinished() {
    return _cached != null;
  }
}
```

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (17993): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (17993): The method 'addAll' was called on null.
I/flutter (17993): Receiver: null
I/flutter (17993): Tried calling: addAll(Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList')
I/flutter (17993):
I/flutter (17993): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (17993): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter (17993): #1      _PathHistory.add (package:painter/painter.dart:133:19)
I/flutter (17993): #2      _PainterState._onPanStart (package:painter/painter.dart:62:43)
I/flutter (17993): #3      DragGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:169:47)
I/flutter (17993): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
I/flutter (17993): #5      DragGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:169:9)
I/flutter (17993): #6      GestureArenaManager._resolveByDefault (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:250:25)
I/flutter (17993): #7      GestureArenaManager._tryToResolveArena.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:231:31)
I/flutter (17993): (elided 2 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (17993):
I/flutter (17993): Handler: onStart
I/flutter (17993): Recognizer:
I/flutter (17993):   PanGestureRecognizer#80c77(debugOwner: GestureDetector)
I/flutter (17993): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (17993): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'addAll' was called on null.
I/flutter (17993): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'addAll' was called on null.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (11464): oh no!
E/flutter (11464): package:painter/painter.dart 39:5                             _PainterState.runAsync
E/flutter (11464): package:painter/painter.dart 35:62                            _PainterState.scheduleAsync.<fn>
E/flutter (11464): package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 129:26  StackZoneSpecification._registerUnaryCallback.<fn>.<fn>
E/flutter (11464): package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 209:15  StackZoneSpecification._run
E/flutter (11464): package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 129:14  StackZoneSpecification._registerUnaryCallback.<fn>
E/flutter (11464): dart:async/zone.dart 1132:38                                  _rootRunUnary
E/flutter (11464): dart:async/zone.dart 1029:19                                  _CustomZone.runUnary
E/flutter (11464): dart:async/future_impl.dart 129:18                            _FutureListener.handleValue
E/flutter (11464): dart:async/future_impl.dart 642:45                            Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
E/flutter (11464): dart:async/future_impl.dart 671:32                            Future._propagateToListeners
E/flutter (11464): dart:async/future_impl.dart 476:7                             Future._complete
E/flutter (11464): dart:async/future.dart 316:16                                 new Future.delayed.<fn>      E/flutter (11464): package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 209:15  StackZoneSpecification._run
E/flutter (11464): package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 119:48  StackZoneSpecification._registerCallback.<fn>
```

Comment: post 4-6 top frames from the stacktrace

Comment: Whatever I am getting the error in console, I added at end of my code.

Comment: in the end, the stack is also given.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception comes from

```
float32list.addAll([startPoint.dx, startPoint.dy]);
```

being called when `float32list` is null as the exception output points out.

```
Float32List float32list;
```

should be

```
Float32List float32list = Float32List.fromList(list);
```

or `float32list` be initialized by other means.